# Content is dropping below left column content - how can I get higher?

Tags: html, css, joomla

My Joomla Rockettheme and component jReview don't work together for some reason. The main content brakes and main part goes below the content on the left side:

http://www.procycling.fi/2/component/content/article/49-kaupat/nettikaupat/774-wiggle

I've had this same issue before, but this time I just can't figure it out. This guy had the same issue some years ago:

http://www.reviewsforjoomla.com/forum/index.php?topic=4384.0

But I don't think adding tables is the right way to go!

Hopefully someone can help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's some CSS issue with your pathway, perhaps try turning it off to see if things work. I've got a screen shot that shows a 'clear' div just below the pathway that's way far down on the screen:  http://www.virtuallin.com/images/div-clr.jpg

Comment: It seems to be the clears indeed, playing around with those values makes the content go up - thanks!